# Implementing fast counter in parallel-bitsliced code

Tags: algorithm, optimization, assembly, simd

I am looking for an optimized implementation of a counter, likely similar to gray-code, that will allow me to rapidly step through numbers in a bitsliced array.

Assuming I have the array:

```
_m256 header[640];
```

I need to keep changing a counter in bits 608 - 639. Each of the 256 bits represents a seperate, parallel counter.

An 'increment' operation takes up to 31 operations: AND to calculate carry, XOR to calculate value, repeated for each position.

Gray-code should only need xor, but I am unaware of an efficient way to calculate the index - it seems to require up to 31 operations to determine a bit position.

Ideally I would like a counter that requires a small number of ALU operations to determine what bit to change.  Does anyone know of something that would be helpful?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you are trying to do. You say "Each of the 256 bits represents a seperate, parallel counter." A 1-bit counter just oscillates between 0, 1, 0, 1, ... And carry is just the inverted value. To calculate the carry, before 'incrementing', you would just take the current value of each counter. To calculate the new value, you just 'not' the counter. That can be done with multiple counters simultaneously by casting to a large datatype (eg int) and taking the bitwise complement (~value).

Comment: There are 256 parallel counters, each 32 bits.  Counter0 uses bit 0 of header[608]..header[639], counter255 uses bit 255 of header[608]..[639].

Answer (score 1):

An LRS can generate a sequence containing all the non-zero numbers 1..2^n-1, using a small number of XORs, but shifting all the bits left at each stage. There is some info at http://www.ee.unb.ca/cgi-bin/tervo/sequence.pl?binary=11111. The number of XORs depends on the number of taps. There is a list of LRS configurations for 32 bits with few taps at http://www.newwaveinstruments.com/resources/articles/m_sequence_linear_feedback_shift_register_lfsr/32stages.txt. Of course the sequence generated is out of order - it is apparently random.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting paper: [The Gray Code](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.105.2467&rep=rep1&type=pdf). (It's a PDF)

Page 16 of the PDF contains an algorithm for finding which bit to toggle. In the general case, it requires 32 operations to determine which bit to change. If you can spare one bit from your counter (which would make it effectively a 31-bit counter), you can make the *average* increment time take fewer operations.

Since the low bit is toggled whenever the parity is even, if you can keep a parity bit then every other increment operation will involve just toggling the low bit. And, of course, you'd toggle the parity bit with every operation.

When parity is odd, you just have to do the part of the algorithm that finds the bit to switch. But since you already know that the parity is odd, you don't have to examine every bit. You can stop when you find the bit that meets the condition.

I'm not familiar enough with SIMD to say if there's any way you can optimize that.

That said, it's not clear to me that such a thing would be an improvement over the "up to 31 operations" that the "regular" binary counter would take. There again, half of your operations will require just one iteration. It seems that the primary advantage of using Gray Code would be that only requires one write to memory (two, if you use the parity bit approach above), whereas the other method could require up to 32 writes to memory.

Comment: Calculating the exact index can be slower as well with the branching penalties. I don't need to cover the entire range, so a counter with fewer states would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement 256 parallel [Linear Shift Feedback Register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register) this way (with base==608)

```
calculate x := header[base+0] XOR header[base+1] XOR header[base+21] XOR header[base+31]
move all elements header[base]...header[base+30] to header[base+1]...header[base+31]
set header[base] := x
```

This will have 2^32-1 different states. If 2^31-1 is sufficient, use taps 27 and 30 instead of 0,1,21,31. The magic numbers are from http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp052.pdf.